# Making Django's CBV's get an instance method

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm currently building a Django app which uses a singleton object.
I want to save this object as a CBV variable because I dont want to initialize it for every 'get' call.

My question in short - can you make a CBV's get function an instance method **instead** of a classmethod?
And if so, can I save a variable as an instance variable?

***EDIT*** - A better explanation to my question:

I created a class that handles a serialized connection with an electronic measurment instrument.
This class must have only 1 instance (singleton), if another instance will be created a memory leak will crash python.

I want to use it with django in the following way:

> Get request to a certain url address -> 
>       The view will ask the instrument class instance for data->
>           Instance responds with data ->
>               View returns a JsonResponse with the data.

I think the best way to do it is making the CBV's get method (whose related to the url im getting from) an instance method, but its not such a good practice..

How should I do it?

Comment: `get` isn't a class method?..

Comment: You could somehow, but why in the world you want to do that.

Comment: @hspandher I need to use a certain class object, and if the get isn't an instancemethod I'll have to re-initialize the object for every get (and when I re-initialize it, ill lose the stored data)

Comment: Surely this is the wrong way round? An instance would be recreated on every request, you would need a class level attribute to preserve state between requests. And `get` *is* an instance method. But you almost certainly shouldn't do this. Please show exactly what you are trying to do so we can recommend a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, `get` *is* an instance method.

But you are confusing responsibilities here. A class should have one responsibility only. The view class has the responsibility of responding to the request and returning a response; this is quite separate from the connection to the instrument. That should be a separate class, which is instantiated at module level and used within the view class.